# Publish a Meteor App in Windows Store

Tags: meteor, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Hello everybody and thanks in advance for responses,

Anybody knows if it's possible to publish a Meteor App in Windows Store. We are thinking to publish it as a Web app. Anybody has tried it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is likely to be deleted, as it is too broad or inviting opinions. You can read the guidelines here on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I'm not sure about web apps in the Windows store, but maybe as a Chrome app? In order to get in the Windows store, you would probably need to build it using Electron as a desktop app

Comment: Sorry @Mikkel, I'm newbie here. I'll be careful in following questions. Thanks for your response.